# Can someone help me understand why this generates a SQL Error

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, COUNT(orderid)
FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customerid)
GROUP BY customerid;
```

I am having a hard time understanding why I am getting `SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` When I perform the count function on its own with this column it works find and even when I used another pk in the select statement it works but alas it doesn't work now and I can use some assistance figuring out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have all non-aggregate columns of `select` in the `group by` [clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) like below.

```
SELECT customerid,lastname, firstname, COUNT(orderid)
FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customerid)
GROUP BY customerid,lastname, firstname; -- all non-aggregate columns
```

Or without CustomerId in output.

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, COUNT(orderid)
FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customerid)
GROUP BY lastname, firstname; -- all non-aggregate columns
```

Comment: Thank you for yore reply! I will re-read about this to get a better understanding but your post helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

[Group by syntax](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php)

When you use a group by clause, your select clause can contain only columns in the group by clause or some aggregate function. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, COUNT(orderid)
FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customerid)
GROUP BY lastname, firstname;
```

Conceptually, it doesn't make sense to have a column that's not a group by column or an aggregate function. In your example query, what does "lastname" or "firstname" really mean when you produce ONE aggregate row for each customerid? Each customerid can have several names associated with it, and your query doesn't specify how to clump them together into one row.

Comment: Thank you! I need to spend some time looking up using aggregate functions and the GROUP BY clause again, but this is a good note to remember.